# Add contents to top div section on clicking button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to two div section TOP and BOTTOM in bottom section i've 3 list records with checkbox and button.

My requirement is when i click on button add clicked record to top div section

Please somebody help me out Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/u74Ag/79/

**Html code**

```
   <div style="border:1px solid #eee;">
<ol style='list-style:decimal;border-bottom:1px solid #e7e7e7;' id="sortable">

</ol> <br/>
</div>
 <br/>


<div>
        <ul id="draggable">
            <li style="height:auto;padding:5px 0;line-height:normal;border-bottom:1px solid #e7e7e7;list-style:none;">
                <div class="qitem" style='margin-bottom : 20px;'>
                    <label>
                        <input class="hello" type="checkbox"/>Value 1
                    </label>
                    <button class="hello" style="float:right;">Add To Top Section</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="height:auto;padding:5px 0;line-height:normal;border-bottom:1px solid #e7e7e7;list-style:none;">
                <div class="qitem" style='margin-bottom : 20px;'>
                    <label>
                        <input class="hello" type="checkbox"/>Value 2
                    </label>
                    <button class="hello" style="float:right;">Add To Top Section</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="height:auto;padding:5px 0;line-height:normal;border-bottom:1px solid #e7e7e7;list-style:none;">
                <div class="qitem" style='margin-bottom : 20px;'>
                    <label>
                        <input class="hello" type="checkbox"/>Value 2
                    </label>
                    <button class="hello" style="float:right;">Add To Top Section</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
                revert: true,
                refreshPositions: true ,
                helper : 'clone',
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                revert: 20
        });

        $("#sortable").disableSelection();

        $(".qitem").draggable({
            tolerance:"pointer",
            helper : 'clone',
            refreshPositions: true ,
            revert : 'invalid',
            opacity:.4,
        });

        $("#sortable").droppable({
            revert:true,
            hoverClass : 'ui-state-highlight',
            greedy: true,
            refreshPositions: true,
            drop : function(ev, ui) 
            {
                $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
                if($(this)[0].id === "sortable")
                {
                    console.log($(this).closest("button").find('.hello'));
                    $(this).find('.hello').hide();
                    $(this).find('.AH_section').show();
                    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' ).closest('li').prependTo(ui.draggable.closest('ul'));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("#sortable").append("<li>item</li>");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oa2hfLum/

Comment: Thank you so much for helping in achieving it but one small request i'm able to push list item above i want value to be pushed above please will u help me out! Thanks!

Comment: Which value do you mean?

Comment: values which are there in bottom div container currently i'm adding item above instead item it would be good for my requirement to add list values kindly go thru the link https://jsfiddle.net/oa2hfLum/2/ Thanks!

Comment: as long as the markup remains the same this should work: https://jsfiddle.net/cdpeuv9d/

Comment: Thanks a tonnnnnnnn u made my day thank you so much for your valuable time and solving my requirement Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe you should spend saved time studying jQuery events (https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) and DOM traversing api (https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) ;)

Comment: Thank you @Radek Michna for your suggestion sure i'll spend my time studying Jquery events Thanks!